# Adding New Admins to Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I am using devise for my users. I recently installed the rails [Active Admin gem](http://activeadmin.info/), everything is working beautifully.

However I can't figure out how to add a new admin users. I can see that active admin created an `admin_user` table in the db with a user admin@example.com, which I use to log in to the interface.

I tried adding `admin_user` as a resource so that I can just click the Add Admin User button within the active admin interface to add a new user, however that does not seem to work.

Comment: Check out step 2 of this tutorial, it may help: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/create-beautiful-administration-interfaces-with-active-admin/

Comment: additional fyi: this is the code Active Admin uses to create the default admin user:  `AdminUser.create!(:email => 'admin@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')`

Answer (score 101, accepted):

What brian said works perfectly
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/create-beautiful-administration-interfaces-with-active-admin/

```
AdminUser.create!(:email => 'admin@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password')
```

Comment: I cannot get this to send an email...any ideas?

Comment: did you see brian's 2nd comment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126747/cant-create-new-user-with-activeadmin/8340729#8340729

Comment: I found emails went out after I re-started my localhost server after changing the active admin files per the tutorial (should have know to do it, but forgot)

Comment: For those new to Rails, first run the rails console, `$ rails c`, then execute the above statement in the console, `# AdminUser.create!(...)`

Answer (score 7):

What Brian said works, but if you want to set the password in the interface rather than have it send a reset email try this:

Leave the admin_user model at its original generated default, then in app/admin/admin_users.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  index do
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :last_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    default_actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this here @Nate914375. Very helpful and didn't have to do much searching around :)

Answer (score 2):

1. login: admin@example.com password: password => login
2. go to http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_users

---

If you want create users (devise users, table "users") in admin panel:

1. $ rails generate active_admin:resource user
2. app/admin/user.rb:

```html
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation

  index do
    column :name
    column :email
    actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'User' do
      f.input :name
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the new syntax 
`AdminUser.create!(email: "youremail@domain.com", password: "password123", password_confirmation: "password123")`

Answer (score 0):

When you'll successfully install the Active Admin, what you've to do is find "seed.rb" which is in "db" folder
Then add this to "seed.rb" file

```
 AdminUser.create!(email: "youremail@domain.com", password: "password123", password_confirmation: "password123")
```

And then run this command in terminal:

```
rails db:seed
```

Answer (score 0):

After installation run the command:-

```
rails db:migrate db:seed
```

This will run the code on the seed file:-

```
AdminUser.create!(
  email: 'admin@example.com',
  password: 'beta123',
  password_confirmation: 'beta123'

)
```