# Adding ActiveAdmin Admins

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin

Rileshttps://gist.github.com/1265585

I'm getting an error (NoMethodError (undefined method `error' for true:TrueClass)) while trying to create a new user in Active Admin.

I followed this tutorial [http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/create-beautiful-administration-interfaces-with-active-admin/] to add an easy way to add new users which I found in this thread [Adding New Admins to Active Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590609/adding-new-admins-to-active-admin)

Anyone able to help out? I imagine it's a simple rails option I'm skipping or a devise stone I'm tripping over.

*Note: ActionMailer doesn't really have domain as the domain.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up answering this awhile ago and it had to deal with misconfiguration on my part elsewhere in the program.