# Can't create new user with ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin

I just added active admin to my rails app and I'm unable to create a new user.  I am using the user model that active admin creates with a few added columns like first and last name.  When I fill out the form for a new user and click create new user, that page refreshes but doesn't save my user and doesn't go to the recap page with the successful message.

here is my AdminUser model

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name

end
```

And here is my active admin class

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  index do
    column :first_name
    column :last_name
    column :email

    default_actions
  end

 form do |f|
   f.inputs "User Details" do
     f.inputs :email
     f.inputs :first_name
     f.inputs :last_name
   end
  f.buttons
 end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgot to add this little guy to the model...fml

```
after_create { |admin| admin.send_reset_password_instructions }

def password_required?
  new_record? ? false : super
end
```

Answer (score 13):

My solution:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params [:email, :password, :password_confirmation] 

  form do |f|
      f.inputs "User" do
        f.input :email
        f.input :password
        f.input :password_confirmation
      end
      f.actions
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is to do with a code reloading bug in Rails which is manifested when your environment specifies `config.cache_classes = false`.

Change that to true in your `config/environments/development.rb`, restart your server, and you should be able to create your user.

However that's not ideal, and one workaround [suggested here](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5497-default-scope-and-class-reloading#ticket-5497-4) is to put the following in your `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
  config.to_prepare do
    Thread.current.keys.each{ |k| Thread.current[k] = nil if k.to_s =~ /_scoped_methods$/ }
  end
```

Although the bug appears to be resolved, I see the issue in 3.1.1 which the above code fixes.

Even though this is a bug in Rails, it's also logged as a [bug in active_admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/733) if you want to see more discussion on this.

Answer (score 0):

Upvoting @Danpe's answer. "Password" is a required field. So you need to add it to permit_params and also ask for password in the form. Only then will it save the form correctly. Here is my permit params string that also fixes other issues with creating a ActiveAdmin user mentioned here : https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2595

```
controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit :utf8, :_method, :authenticity_token, :commit, :id,
                model: [:attribute1, :attribute2, etc]
    end
end
```

Comment: Naren i followed this solution and it solves the unpermitted problem but however i do not know why it doesn't do an update action. I tried updating record, but after patch action, it rollback. Do you have any idea why ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971627/activeadmin-after-create-redirecting-to-show-update-actions-error