# Password "can't be blank" when trying to create a new user via ActiveAdmin in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

My setup - Rails 4, ActiveAdmin, Devise generated User model. The users authenticate with usernames and do not have the email attribute. I am mentioning the last, as Devise heavily relies on the email attribute, so this might have to do with the problem. My exact setup and code are described [in this blog post](http://alexvpopov.github.io/blog/2013/10/31/allow-users-to-authenticate-with-username-only-using-devise-activeadmin-rails-4-and-ruby-2/).

In ActiveAdmin back-end, I go to Users -> New User -> fill in username, password, password confirmation -> Create User. Instead of creating a new user the New User form gets wiped out and under the Password field I get the error `can't be blank`. When I go to the Rails console and create a new user manually `User.create(username: 'Joe', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')` everything works and the user is able to log in at `localhost:3000/users/sign_in`.

I saw this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126747/cant-create-new-user-with-activeadmin). If I add to my User model:

```
def password_required?
  new_record? ? false : super
end
```

I can create a new user, but all of the fields (including username, encrypted password) are blank.

**UPDATE** As Leger suggest, I am posting my code. As I am using the built-in contrllers of Devise and Activeadmin, I think it only makes sense to post the code of my User resource in Activeadmin and my db schema:

User resource in Activeadmin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  # This determines which attributes of the User model will be displayed in the index page. I have left only username, but feel free to uncomment the rest of the lines or add any other of the User attributes.
  index do
    column :username
    # column :current_sign_in_at
    # column :last_sign_in_at
    # column :sign_in_count
    default_actions
  end

  # Default is :email, but we need to replace this with :username
  filter :username

  # This is the form for creating a new user using the Admin backend. If you have added additional attributes to the User model, you need to include them here.
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "User Details" do
      f.input :username
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end

  # This is related to Rails 4 and the changes it introduced in handling strong parameters. Here we replace :email with :username.
  controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit admin_user: [:username, :password, :password_confirmation]
    end
  end
end
```

schema.rb:

```
ctiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131031102826) do

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "namespace"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "resource_id",   null: false
    t.string   "resource_type", null: false
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.string   "author_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id"
  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"
  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"

  create_table "admin_users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "admin_users", ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "admin_users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "username",               default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true

end
```

Any other code is available [here](https://github.com/AlexVPopov/devise-username-only).

Comment: I would recommend to post relevant code from view and controller here. Quite  often it helps.

Comment: Thank you, @Leger, I provided the code as you suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the `permitted_params` method in your ActiveAdmin page handling the `User` model:

```
params.permit admin_user: [:username, :password, :password_confirmation]
```

If this is actually the `User` model, the line should read:

```
params.permit user: [:username, :password, :password_confirmation]
```

That fits the simptoms you describe–empty form after submit and everything working properly in the console.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!!! I had copied the body of the AdminUser resource into the User resource and than just changed some parts, which once again shows why copy-pasting is a VERY BAD idea.